# Line-based heatmap or 2D line histogram

Tags: python, plot, heatmap

I have a synthetic dataset with 1000 noisy polygons of various orders and sin/cos curves that I can plot as lines using python seaborn.

[image]

Since I have quite a few lines that are overlapping, I'd like to plot some sort of heatmap or histogram of my line graphs. 
I've tried iterating over the columns and aggregating the counts to use seaborn's heatmap graph, but with many lines this takes quite a while.

The next best thing that results in what I want was a hexbin graph (with seaborn jointgraph).

[image]

But it's a compromise between runtime and granularity (the shown graph has gridsize 750). I couldn't find any other graph-type for my problem. But I also don't know exactly what it might be called.

I've also tried with line alpha set to 0.2. This results in a similar graph to what I want. But it's less precise (if more than 5 lines overlap at the same point I already have zero transparency left). Also, it misses the typical coloration of heatmaps.

(Moot search terms were: heatmap, 2D line histogram, line histogram, density plots...)

Does anybody know packages to plot this **more efficiently and high(er) quality** or knows how to do it with the popular python plotters (i.e. the matplotlib family: matplotlib, seaborn, bokeh). I'm really fine with any package though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It took me awhile, but I finally solved this using [Datashader](http://datashader.org/). If using a notebook, the plots can be embedded into interactive [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/) plots, which looks really nice.

Anyhow, here is the code for static images, in case someone else is in need of something similar:

```
# coding: utf-8
import time

import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import polynomial
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datashader as ds
import datashader.transfer_functions as tf


plt.style.use("seaborn-whitegrid")

def create_data():
    # ...

# Each column is one data sample
df = create_data()

# Following will append a nan-row and reshape the dataframe into two columns, with each sample stacked on top of each other
#   THIS IS CRUCIAL TO OPTIMIZE SPEED: https://github.com/bokeh/datashader/issues/286

# Append row with nan-values
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([np.array([np.nan] * len(df.columns))], columns=df.columns, index=[np.nan]))

# Reshape
x, y = df.shape
arr = df.as_matrix().reshape((x * y, 1), order='F')
df_reshaped = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=list('y'), index=np.tile(df.index.values, y))
df_reshaped = df_reshaped.reset_index()
df_reshaped.columns.values[0] = 'x'

# Plotting parameters
x_range = (min(df.index.values), max(df.index.values))
y_range = (df.min().min(), df.max().max())
w = 1000
h = 750
dpi = 150
cvs = ds.Canvas(x_range=x_range, y_range=y_range, plot_height=h, plot_width=w)

# Aggregate data
t0 = time.time()
aggs = cvs.line(df_reshaped, 'x', 'y', ds.count())
print("Time to aggregate line data: {}".format(time.time()-t0))

# One colored plot
t1 = time.time()
stacked_img = tf.Image(tf.shade(aggs, cmap=["darkblue", "darkblue"]))
print("Time to create stacked image: {}".format(time.time() - t1))

# Save
f0 = plt.figure(figsize=(w / dpi, h / dpi), dpi=dpi)
ax0 = f0.add_subplot(111)
ax0.imshow(stacked_img.to_pil())
ax0.grid(False)
f0.savefig("stacked.png", bbox_inches="tight", dpi=dpi)

# Heat map - This uses a equalized histogram (built-in default), there are other options, though.
t2 = time.time()
heatmap_img = tf.Image(tf.shade(aggs, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral_r))
print("Time to create stacked image: {}".format(time.time() - t2))

# Save
f1 = plt.figure(figsize=(w / dpi, h / dpi), dpi=dpi)
ax1 = f1.add_subplot(111)
ax1.imshow(heatmap_img.to_pil())
ax1.grid(False)
f1.savefig("heatmap.png", bbox_inches="tight", dpi=dpi)
```

With following run times (in seconds):

```
Time to aggregate line data: 0.7710442543029785
Time to create stacked image: 0.06000351905822754
Time to create stacked image: 0.05600309371948242
```

The resulting plots:
[image: Stacked lines]

[image: Heatmap]

Answer (score 1):

Although it seems you have tried this, plotting the counts seems to give a good representation of the data. However, it really depends what you're trying to find in your data, what is it supposed to tell you?

The reason for the long run time is due to plotting so many lines, a heatmap based on the counts however will plot fairly quickly.

I created some dummy data for sinus waves, based on noise, no. of lines, amplitude and shift. Added both a boxplot and heatmap.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import random
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

#create dummy data
N = 200
sinuses = []
no_lines = 200
for i in range(no_lines):
    a = np.random.randint(5, 40)/5 #amplitude
    x = random.choice([int(N/5),  int(N/(2/5))]) #random shift
    sinuses.append(np.roll(a * np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, N))  + np.random.randn(N), x))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20 / 2.54, 20 / 2.54))
sins = pd.DataFrame(sinuses, )

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,10), (0,0), colspan=10)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,10), (1,0), colspan=10)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3,10), (2,0), colspan=9)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((3,10), (2,9))

# plot line data
sins.T.plot(ax=ax1, color='lightblue',linewidth=.3)
ax1.legend_.remove()
ax1.set_xlim(0, N)

# try boxplot
sins.plot.box(ax=ax2, showfliers=False)
xticks = ax2.xaxis.get_major_ticks()
for index, label in enumerate(ax2.get_xaxis().get_ticklabels()):
    xticks[index].set_visible(False)  # hide ticks where labels are hidden

#make a list of bins
no_bins = 20
bins = list(np.arange(sins.min().min(), sins.max().max(), int(abs(sins.min().min())+sins.max().max())/no_bins))
bins.append(sins.max().max())

# calculate histogram
hists = []
for col in sins.columns:
    count, division = np.histogram(sins.iloc[:,col], bins=bins)
    hists.append(count)
hists = pd.DataFrame(hists, columns=[str(i) for i in bins[1:]])
print(hists.shape, '\n', hists.head())

cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['white', '#FFFFBB', '#C3FDB8', '#B5EAAA', '#64E986', '#54C571',
          '#4AA02C', '#347C17', '#347235', '#25383C', '#254117'])

#heatmap
im = ax3.pcolor(hists.T, cmap=cmap)
cbar = plt.colorbar(im, cax=ax4)

yticks = np.arange(0, len(bins))
yticklabels = hists.columns.tolist()
ax3.set_yticks(yticks)
ax3.set_yticklabels([round(i,1) for i in bins])
ax3.set_title('Count')
yticks = ax3.yaxis.get_major_ticks()

for index, label in enumerate(ax3.get_yaxis().get_ticklabels()):
    if index % 3 != 0: #make some labels invisible
        yticks[index].set_visible(False)  # hide ticks where labels are hidden

plt.show()
```

[image]

Although the boxplot is easy to interpret, it doesn't show the actual distribution of the data very well, but knowing where the median and quantiles lie may be helpful.

Increasing the number of lines and amount of values per line will increase plotting time considerably for the line plots, the heatmap is still fairly quick though to generate. The boxplot becomes indiscernible however.

[image]

I couldn't exactly replicate your data (or know the actual size of it), but perhaps the heatmap may be helpful.