# Line density heatmap in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, heatmap

**Problem description**
I have thousands of lines (~4000) that I want to plot. However it is infeasible to plot all lines using `geom_line()` and just use for example `alpha=0.1` to illustrate where there is a high density of lines and where not. I came across [something similar in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175398/line-based-heatmap-or-2d-line-histogram), especially the second plot of the answers looks really nice, but I do not now if something similar can be achieved in `ggplot2`. Thus something like this:
[image]

**An example dataset**
It would make much more sense to demonstrate this with a set showing a pattern, but for now I just generated random sinus curves:

```
set.seed(1)
gen.dat <- function(key) {
    c <- sample(seq(0.1,1, by = 0.1), 1)
    time <- seq(c*pi,length.out=100)
    val <- sin(time)
    time = 1:100
    data.frame(time,val,key)
}
dat <- lapply(seq(1,10000), gen.dat) %>% bind_rows()
```

**Tried heatmap**
I tried a heatmap [like answered here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31726/scatterplot-with-contour-heat-overlay), however this heatmap will not consider the connection of points over the complete axis (like in a line) but rather show the "heat" **per** time point.

**Question**
How can we in R, using `ggplot2` plot a heatmap of lines simmilar to that shown in the first figure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data will result in a quite uniform polkadot density.

I generated some slightly more interesting data like this:

```
gen.dat <- function(key) {
  has_offset <- runif(1) > 0.5
  time <- seq(1, 1000, length.out = 1000)
  val <- sin(time / 100 + rnorm(1, sd = 0.2) + (has_offset * 1.5)) * 
    rgamma(1, 20, 20)
  data.frame(time,val,key)
}
dat <- lapply(seq(1,1000), gen.dat) %>% bind_rows()
```

We then get a 2d density estimate.  kde2d doesn't have a `predict` function so we model it with a LOESS

```
dens <- MASS::kde2d(dat$time, dat$val, n = 400)
dens_df <- data.frame(with(dens, expand_grid( y, x)), z = as.vector(dens$z))
fit <- loess(z ~ y * x, data = dens_df, span = 0.02)
dat$z <- predict(fit, with(dat, data.frame(x=time, y=val)))
```

Plotting it then gets this result:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(time, val, group = key, color = z)) +
  geom_line(size = 0.05) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = c("blue", "yellow", "red"))
```

[image]

This is all highly reliant on:

- The number of series
- The resolution of series
- The density of kde2d
- The span of loess

so your mileage may vary

Comment: Try out Tjebo's library suggestion on my data with `ggplot(dat, aes(time, val, group=key)) +stat_pointdensity(geom = "line", size = 0.05, adjust = 10) + scale_color_gradientn(colors = c("blue", "yellow", "red"))`

Comment: That's nice indeed. Thanks for providing a nice sample data and indeed, this looks great with `ggpointdensity`

Comment: Have updated my answer with your data. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you for the bountry, Tjebo :) I think ultimately ggpointdensity achieves a nicer looking hearmap. I wonder if its density is accurate as the density at ~250, -0.5 is similar to the one at 375 -0.5 but that could just be the gradient

Answer (score 6):

Looking closely, one can see that the graph to which you are linking consists of **many, many, many** points rather than lines.

The `ggpointdensity` package does a similar visualisation. Note with so many data points, there are quite some performance issues. I am using the developer version, because it contains the `method` argument which allows to use different smoothing estimators and apparently helps deal better with larger numbers. There is a CRAN version too.

You can adjust the smoothing with the `adjust` argument.

I have increased the x interval density of your code, to make it look more like lines. Have slightly reduced the number of 'lines' in the plot though.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#devtools::install_github("LKremer/ggpointdensity")
library(ggpointdensity)

set.seed(1)
gen.dat <- function(key) {
  c <- sample(seq(0.1,1, by = 0.1), 1)
  time <- seq(c*pi,length.out=500)
  val <- sin(time)
  time = seq(0.02,100,0.1)
  data.frame(time,val,key)
}
dat <- lapply(seq(1, 1000), gen.dat) %>% bind_rows()

ggplot(dat, aes(time, val)) + 
  geom_pointdensity(size = 0.1, adjust = 10) 
#> geom_pointdensity using method='kde2d' due to large number of points (>20k)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**update**
Thanks [user Robert Gertenbach for creating some more interesting sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60839720/7941188). Here the suggested use of ggpointdensity on this data:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpointdensity)

gen.dat <- function(key) {
  has_offset <- runif(1) > 0.5
  time <- seq(1, 1000, length.out = 1000)
  val <- sin(time / 100 + rnorm(1, sd = 0.2) + (has_offset * 1.5)) * 
    rgamma(1, 20, 20)
  data.frame(time,val,key)
}

dat <- lapply(seq(1,1000), gen.dat) %>% bind_rows()
ggplot(dat, aes(time, val, group=key)) +stat_pointdensity(geom = "line", size = 0.05, adjust = 10) + scale_color_gradientn(colors = c("blue", "yellow", "red"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Technically every line and scatter (point) plot can be interchanged, but it depends on the underlying data - were the in my question provided images clearly aims to show a **pattern/correlation** rather than the **"jitter"** of points. To illustrate, in your plot the underlying, characterizing sinus structure is not apparent.

Comment: @CodeNoob the sample data may not be ideal. I find it possible to see the pattern - it is naturally creating a regular grid. In general,  if you convert lines to points, the method should work. But that's also the reason why I put a bounty on your question, because there may be better ideas for solutions out there. Find this an interesting problem.

Comment: @codenoob if you struggle to see the pattern, make the image smaller, so that you stop to see the single dots. the same happens in the example image which you provided. it’s a matter of resolution.

Comment: Using this on my data with `ggplot(dat, aes(time, val, group=key)) +stat_pointdensity(geom = "line", size = 0.05, adjust = 10) + scale_color_gradientn(colors = c("blue", "yellow", "red"))` results in something really good looking!

Answer (score -1):

I came up with the following solution, using `geom_segment()`, however I'm not sure if `geom_segment()` is the way to go as it then only checks if pairwise values are **exactly** the same whereas in a heatmap (as in my question) values near each other also affect the 'heat' rather than being exactly the same.

```
# Simple stats to get all possible line segments
vals <- unique(dat$time)
min.val = min(vals)
max.val = max(vals)

# Get all possible line segments
comb.df <- data.frame(
  time1 = min.val:(max.val - 1),
  time2 = (min.val + 1): max.val
)

# Join the original data to all possible line segments
comb.df <- comb.df %>% 
  left_join(dat %>% select(time1 = time, val1 = val, key )) %>%
  left_join(dat %>% select(time2 = time, val2 = val, key ))

# Count how often each line segment occurs in the data
comb.df <- comb.df %>% 
  group_by(time1, time2, val1, val2) %>%
  summarise(n = n_distinct(key))

# ggplot2 to plot segments
ggplot(comb.df %>% arrange(n)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = time1, y = val1, xend = time2, yend = val2, color = n), alpha =0.9) +
  scale_colour_gradient( low = 'green', high = 'red')  +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]