# GPS Heatmap with ggplot (geom_Path)

Tags: r, ggplot2, gps, geospatial, heatmap

I would like to create something similar to this:

[image: Cool heatmap]

With my runs using ggplot2:

Imho the best way to achieve that is using geom_path but I’m faced with some problems.
My db has 3 columns:
ID (the id of the run, useful to group the data)
Lat
Lon
Here there is a sample:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lUUwVUzt4wCvbDLSrusfH9pVFXw-8icC8mLJ0QKBYKU/edit?usp=sharing

PS. Sorry data is too big for dput

1: How to calculate the intensity of the path. I was thinking about count the number of coordinates (lat, lon) within a range (e.g. 50m). 
So a couple of lat,lon with a lot of number of coordinates near it. It is a point with a high intensity. The problem is the dimesionality of data. I have tons of rows and my computational power cannot calculated this big matrix (famous error: cannot allocate vector of.).
My solution to get past the error is a loop that calculates the distance for each row:

```
npoints_2<-c()
for (i in 1:nrow(db)){
  vector_distance<-distm(db[i,2:3], db[-i,2:3], fun = distHaversine)  #for each row calculate the distance between the point and the dataset
  npoints<-sum(vector_distance<50) #count points within 50m
  npoints_2<-c(npoints_2,npoints)
}
```

Since it is a loop, this solution is very slow (and not possible).
There must be a smarter solution but probably I'm too noob, so please help me.

The result of this approach with a few runs is this one:

```
ggplot(db, aes(lon,lat, group=id,color = log(n_punti_2))) + 
geom_path() +
scale_colour_continuous(low = "darkblue", high = "cyan")
```

[image: Little sample]

This introduces the second problem: similar routes with little differences in term of coordinates.

[image: A little zoom for better understanding]

Which is the best way to combined together similar routes? Imho for graphical reason is better have one single line with a high intensity than 2/3/n pretty similar lines with similar intensity

Thanks in advance for your help. It's very appreciate!!!

Comment: very related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60721403/line-density-heatmap-in-r

Comment: P.S. Welcome to SO. If you want better help, please create a reproducible example, including sample data. Doesn't need to be big, but it should be able to get to the core of the problem.

Comment: Sample of DB added.

Comment: Added with Google Sheets, I don't know if it is correct for policy question of stackoverflow but dput was not enough for a reproducible example. The source of the map is: strava heatmap, a popular social network for sports

Comment: @Tjebo Strava heatmaps globally available at https://www.strava.com/heatmap#12.58/-0.10955/51.51965/hot/all by zooming and panning. You'll need to be a member to see more detailed maps

Comment: I've done similar with my strava output, and found one way to achieve a similar effect with limited effort was to use a low value of alpha, e.g. 0.3 for geom_path

Comment: @Tjebo: https://mappinglondon.co.uk/2018/strava-labs-heatmap-of-runners/ this is the source of the map that I used. As Miff said you can check the entire heatmap of Strava following the link: https://www.strava.com/heatmap#7.00/-120.90000/38.36000/hot/all        PS. I reload the data on google sheet. Hopefully the format it is correct now. Thank you for your answer, I will check asap the functioning of geom point density (sincerly, I don't know it).

Comment: @Miff, yes I already tried to manage only the alpha values but I'm not satisfied at all with the results.

Comment: Cheers for the link. It gives some details on how they did it. Unfortunately not in R. But you may get some ideas : https://medium.com/strava-engineering/the-global-heatmap-now-6x-hotter-23fc01d301de

Comment: I've updated my answer with the new data

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to emulate the Strava-look a bit better - one realises how great the job is that the creators of those maps do. If you zoom in to those maps, you can see that those lines are really nicely rendered.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpointdensity)

runs <- read.csv("your_path.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ggplot(runs, aes(lon, lat)) +
  geom_pointdensity(size = .8) +
  scale_color_gradient2(low = "#340707", mid = "#d95e23", high = "#fffdee",
                        midpoint = 3500
                        ) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = '#160e16'),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see using your included data, but it is possible.

Using the `sf` package and ggplot2, you can plot the points twice and change the color and alpha in the second call.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

#Read File 
x <- read_csv(#Your file location here)

#Change file to sf object
x <- st_as_sf(x, coords = c('lon', 'lat')) %>% st_set_crs(4326)

# Plot the paths twice.  Once in white and again with a different color.
#  Set alpha level of second plot to allow a 'bleed through' of the
#  first color.
ggplot(x) + 
  geom_sf(color = 'orangered4', size = .1) +
  geom_sf(alpha = .03, color = 'white', size = .1) + 
  theme_void() + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'black'))
```

The track you ran shows up as closer to white since there are many points there, and the beginning and end of the run along the coast are darker where there are fewer points.

[image]