# Visualizing timeseries in R - Color lines based on how close each line is to the mean of the cluster

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have clustered my time-series gene expression data based on their temporal expression.
Given that there is some variation in the temporal trends, I would like to visualize where most of the lines are to get a more evident trend. One way that I was thinking to do it is to color the lines based on how close they are to the mean trend of the cluster but I have no idea how to implement that.

A reproducible example of my data:

```
dat <- structure(list(gene_name = c("NIPAL3", "NIPAL3", "NIPAL3", "NIPAL3", 
"NIPAL3", "SEMA3F", "SEMA3F", "SEMA3F", "SEMA3F", "SEMA3F", "AOC1", 
"AOC1", "AOC1", "AOC1", "AOC1", "ZMYND10", "ZMYND10", "ZMYND10", 
"ZMYND10", "ZMYND10", "ACSM3", "ACSM3", "ACSM3", "ACSM3", "ACSM3", 
"PDK2", "PDK2", "PDK2", "PDK2", "PDK2", "TMEM132A", "TMEM132A", 
"TMEM132A", "TMEM132A", "TMEM132A", "ALDH3B1", "ALDH3B1", "ALDH3B1", 
"ALDH3B1", "ALDH3B1", "USH1C", "USH1C", "USH1C", "USH1C", "USH1C", 
"NOS2", "NOS2", "NOS2", "NOS2", "NOS2"), Sample.name = c("DMSO_1", 
"DMSO_2", "DMSO_24", "DMSO_4", "DMSO_8", "DMSO_1", "DMSO_2", 
"DMSO_24", "DMSO_4", "DMSO_8", "DMSO_1", "DMSO_2", "DMSO_24", 
"DMSO_4", "DMSO_8", "DMSO_1", "DMSO_2", "DMSO_24", "DMSO_4", 
"DMSO_8", "DMSO_1", "DMSO_2", "DMSO_24", "DMSO_4", "DMSO_8", 
"DMSO_1", "DMSO_2", "DMSO_24", "DMSO_4", "DMSO_8", "DMSO_1", 
"DMSO_2", "DMSO_24", "DMSO_4", "DMSO_8", "DMSO_1", "DMSO_2", 
"DMSO_24", "DMSO_4", "DMSO_8", "DMSO_1", "DMSO_2", "DMSO_24", 
"DMSO_4", "DMSO_8", "DMSO_1", "DMSO_2", "DMSO_24", "DMSO_4", 
"DMSO_8"), Treatment = c("DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", 
"DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", 
"DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", 
"DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", 
"DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", 
"DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", 
"DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO", "DMSO"), Time = c(1, 2, 5, 3, 
4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 
1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 
2, 5, 3, 4), counts = c(-0.674728025769495, -1.36397354466049, 
0.610379522258895, -1.14928773078363, -0.446571694189183, -0.436985550549815, 
-0.499130283673904, -0.450641960945776, -0.827458887288972, -0.245426299345142, 
-0.305285624771504, -0.640229241821068, 0.167251080770738, -1.09858244762228, 
-0.567447650338103, -0.609472980799307, 0.115975465710009, -2.43581298419879, 
-0.085029879459607, -0.604272206569522, -0.559054804869209, -0.827020967548349, 
0.168793788002722, -0.951210549139716, 0.15852569469711, -0.724991719902859, 
-1.04664568307064, -0.828798242883774, -1.15973081519968, -0.574087099835571, 
-0.0620293805158624, -0.235285085548273, -0.830591518382229, 
-0.469245592463803, -0.0521555714928603, -0.477982049612678, 
-0.59701614315213, 0.208614404395684, -1.00028569852069, -0.503026174159395, 
-0.631726558325577, -0.60884838805659, -0.0250059525913151, -0.680997114400299, 
-0.249988532737743, -0.856318481580249, -0.811356236427306, -0.48845066252092, 
-0.928288203615435, -0.508993568295652)), row.names = c(NA, -50L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Gene_name column contains the genes that I have used for clustering.
Sample name contains the biological conditions the measurements were taken and the time. E.g DMSO_1 corresponds to the measurement in DMSO samples at 1h. The same information are found also in two separate columns (i.e. Treatment and Time)
The counts column correspond to the mean, scaled counts of a gene, and  the cluster column is the cluster that each gene was assigned (in total I have 8 clusters).

I am plotting my data using

```
dat_r%>% 
  ggplot(aes(Time, counts)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = gene_name, alpha = 0.3)) +
  geom_smooth(stat = "summary", fun = "mean")
```

An example of a cluster I am getting using the code above with my complete data.

[image]

and an example of the desired output is (taken from [here](https://www.aging-us.com/figure/102667/f2))

[image]

I have tried to use the following code to color each line based on its distance from the mean trend of a cluster.

```
  dat %>%
    group_by(gene_name) %>%
    mutate(gene_var = counts - mean(counts, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(Time,counts, color = gene_var)) +
    geom_line(aes(group = gene_name, alpha = 0.3)) +
    scale_color_distiller(palette = "YlOrRd")
```

but the returning plot is not coloring the line with one color.

[image]

Comment: very related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60721403/line-density-heatmap-in-r

Comment: Indeed. Unfortunately, the answers there did not work for me.

Comment: would each line have only one color like in the example or would the color be allowed to change?

Comment: I would like to have the line as one color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a go using the `storms` data from `dplyr`. I calculate each storms RMSE vs the average windspeed trajectory. Maybe not the best example but I think it does what you want.

```
# make some example data
storms_sample <- storms %>%
  group_by(name, year) %>%
  transmute(wind, obs = row_number()) %>%
  filter(obs <= 60, max(obs) >= 55)

# calculate RMSE for each storm, and plot based on that
storms_sample %>%
  group_by(obs) %>%
  mutate(obs_var = wind - mean(wind, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(name, year) %>%
  mutate(storm_var = sqrt(mean(obs_var^2))) %>%
  ungroup() %>% # EDIT - might fix OP's problem
  filter(!storm_var %>% between(15,30)) %>% # Edit to highlight extremes
  
  ggplot(aes(obs, wind, group = interaction(name,year), color = storm_var)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_color_distiller(palette = "YlOrRd") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

EDIT - here's code I tried on the new sample data, which seems to work -- e.g. there's a gene_var that doesn't follow the trend which is much more yellow than the others.

```
dat %>%
  group_by(Time) %>%
  mutate(var = counts - mean(counts, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(gene_name) %>%
  mutate(gene_var = sqrt(mean(var^2))) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(Time, counts, group = gene_name, color = gene_var)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_distiller(palette = "YlOrRd") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: This is very close to what I want. However, when I implement it on my data, I get a different color at each time point. I have edited my post to include the format of my data, in case that helps. Thanks!

Comment: In my case the x axis is "obs" and I'm using "year" to distinguish storms with the same name but different years. I don't know how you're implementing it in your data, but I think you'll want `aes(group = Gene_name, color = [variable calculated to summarize that gene's distance from mean] )`

Comment: I think I am a bit confused regarding which variables to use for the grouping. What I have tried so far is the following ```gene_clusters %>%
  group_by(Gene_name) %>%
  mutate(gene_var = counts - mean(counts, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  group_by(Cluster) %>%
  mutate(counts_var = sqrt(mean(gene_var^2))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Time, counts, color = gene_var)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Gene_name, alpha = 0.3)) +
  scale_color_distiller(palette = "YlOrRd") ```

Comment: You question doesn't currently have enough information for us to know what you have and what you want. I don't know what the difference between `Gene_name` and `Cluster` and `gene_var` is; I would have guessed you would want to use `counts_var` as your color mapping and `Cluster` for your group mapping?

Comment: Sorry I did not initally include sufficient information. I have now updated my post with explanation about my data structure and an example of the output I get when applying the above code. Using `count_var` for mapping results in a plot where all lines are colored the same

Comment: I notice you group by Cluster but never ungroup; in my example my lines are each unique `name,year` which was my grouping variable for the variance calculation, but in yours you have both `Gene_name` and `Cluster` and it's still unclear why you are calculating based on Cluster but giving each `Gene_name` its own line. Might be fixed by ungrouping after the variance calc or by leaving cluster out of it and calculating variance based on `Gene_name`?

Comment: I grouped by Cluster because I have eight different clusters, so I wanted to calculate the mean separately, but it is indeed unnecessary since each gene can be part of a one cluster. I tried ```clusters_values %>%
  group_by(PTM_id) %>% 
  mutate(gene_var = intensity - mean(intensity, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Time, intensity, color = gene_var)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = PTM_id)) +
  scale_color_distiller(palette = "YlOrRd")``` but I get again the same figure as Fig3 in my post. The line colors seem to be calculated differently between time intervals. Ungroup does not help either.

Comment: Happy to help further if you can make your question reproducible.

Comment: Thank you for time you have spent already. I have now updated my post with sample data and updated code.

Comment: Edited with attempt which I think is doing what you want.